# How to Extract Textview value to save in Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, database, textview, sharedpreferences

I have this User Profile where the data comes from Database (`SQL`) so my `textview` value comes from database and not from user input. How can I save the value that is set to my `Textview` from Database. Images attached.

Data Successfully Displayed

[image: image 1]

I need to save those values to Shared Preferences so when the activity destroys I can display the data again.

Data Lost

[image: image 2]

This is my codes getting the intent from the database thrown-ed by log in.

```
greetingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting_text_view);
        totpoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.au_tpresult);
        totshare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.au_tsresult);
        btnLogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
        cardshow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user = intent.getStringExtra("customers_firstname");
        String user1 = intent.getStringExtra("customers_lastname");
        String user2 = intent.getStringExtra("reward_points");
        String user3 = intent.getStringExtra("NoShares");
        String user4 = intent.getStringExtra("CardType_ID");
        String user5 = intent.getStringExtra("Card_No");


        greetingTextView.setText(user + " " + user1);
        totpoints.setText(user2);
        totshare.setText(user3);


        if (user4 == (null)) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack)).setImageResource(R.drawable.thar_silver);
        } else if (user4.equals("0")) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack)).setImageResource(R.drawable.thar_silver);
        } else if (user4.equals("1")) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack)).setImageResource(R.drawable.thar_gold);

        }

        // Progress dialog
        btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                session.logoutUser();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivityEN.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        session.checkLogin();

        //CARD NUMBER to Bitmap to Barcode


        // barcode data
        String barcode_data = user5;

        // barcode image
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        bmbc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap_barcode);
        bmbc_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap_barcode_text);

        try {

            bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 800, 150);
            bmbc.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            bmbc_text.setText(user5);


        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    String output_name, output_points, output_share, output_id;


    output_name = greetingTextView.getText().toString();
    output_points = totpoints.getText().toString();
    output_share = totshare.getText().toString();
    output_id =  bmbc_text.getText().toString();

    session.createUserSession(output_name, output_points, output_share, output_id);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session Override", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    session.getUserDetails();

    if (session != null) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AFCOOP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String getvaluefromname = sharedPreferences.getString("custoname", new String());
        String getvaluefrompoints = sharedPreferences.getString("totalpoints", new String());


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        greetingTextView.setText(getvaluefromname);
        totpoints.setText(getvaluefrompoints);



    } else if (session == null) {
    }
}
```

The last part is not working because only the user input is saved in Shared Preferences. I need to extract the value from Text view and save it in Shared Preferences and the display it. Thank you!

MySessionManager

// Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

```
// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "AFCOOP";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_UNAME = "custoname";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_UPOINTS = "totalpoints";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_USHARE = "totalshare";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_UCARDNUM = "cardnumber";




// Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String name, String password) {
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, password);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

public void createUserSession(String custoname, String totalpoints, String totalshare, String cardnumber){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_UNAME, custoname);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_UPOINTS, totalpoints);
    // Storing email in pref

    editor.putString(KEY_USHARE, totalshare);
    // Storing email in pref

    editor.putString(KEY_UCARDNUM, cardnumber);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 * */
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivityEN.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Starting Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

}





/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // user name
    user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

    // user email id
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    user.put(KEY_UNAME, pref.getString(KEY_UNAME, null));

    user.put(KEY_UPOINTS, pref.getString(KEY_UPOINTS, null));

    user.put(KEY_USHARE, pref.getString(KEY_USHARE, null));

    user.put(KEY_UCARDNUM, pref.getString(KEY_UCARDNUM, null));



    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivityEN.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * Quick check for login
 * **/
// Get Login State
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

}
```

}

Comment: you already are taking the values from texviews in strings . And you are saying that these values are not being saved ?

Comment: What action causes the data loss? If it's an event that destroys the activity and then recreates it (such as screen rotation), you can use `savedInstanceState` bundle. Read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: @Umair yes, it is not saved in my shared preference when I am trying to display saved value it gives me nothing.

Comment: @RJDC then that means your method "create userSession" is not working fine. Debug your code and I think there is some exception there or it is due to the context you are passing to it.
The strings will be taking the values from textviews for sure.

Comment: @NeriaNachum The data that is displayed before destroyed is from the database, the action data kills the activity is when I go to different buttons like home, then going back to the user profile, because the intent that is sending the data is the login page.

Comment: @Umair this is the part I am trying to save

session.createUserSession(output_name, output_points, output_share, output_id);

from default it should be ("custoname", "totalpoints", "totalshare", "cardnumber") 

but it will be static string as it is.

Comment: @RJDC Store your run time data in a class-level variable(s). For examples you can make the strings `user`, `user1`, etc class-level variables, although I recommend to make a POJO class for your data model.

Comment: I solved the issue, I input the data to shared preference the same time as the database return values, so I entered the values to Shared prefs not even before displaying it to textview so I dont need to extract the value anymore. Thank you for your time @Umair and Neria, Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make a static function instead of constructor and initialize it in your main activity like below.

```
public static void initialize(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```

Main Activity

```
SharePreferences myPref; //Global Variable
```

Inside onCreate

```
myPref = SessionManger.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Now you can use your shared prefs.

I would recomment you to put getter also inside SessionManager Class

Also ,Is Private_Mode value 0? Can you try to use the one defined in Android Constants Context.MODE_PRIVATE.